# How to get password without changing it in linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, users

I have linux server ubuntu 20.04
Any command to show you password belong to user ? or a file in server which can show passwords?

Comment: Why you need that? What is the core problem you're solving?

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming that you're talking about login passwords)

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: no - because the passwords held in the password file are encrypted in a method which cannot be decrypted. What essentially happens at login time is that the password you supply is encrypted and compared against that held in the file.